# Why the parenthesis for the output -CenterDot[x,y]?

Tags: output-formatting

Why do

```
2 CenterDot[x,y]
- CenterDot[x,y]
```

produce output that looks like $2 \, x\cdot y$ for the former but $-(x\cdot y)$ with parentheses for the latter?

Both have `FullForm` of the form `Times[n,Centerdot[x,y]]`, and normally `Times[n,x]` does not produce any parentheses when $n$ happens to be $-1$.
The parentheses can be suppressed by writing `PrecedenceForm[CenterDot[x, y], 490]`, yet not with `PrecedenceForm[CenterDot[x, y], 489]`; I do not quite understand why this is the case as `Precendence[Times]=400.` and `Precendence[CenterDot]=410.` are both rather lower.

Comment: feel free to make the title and tags more precise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that unary minus has higher precedence than CenterDot:

```
Precedence[Minus]
Precedence[CenterDot]
```

> 480.
>
> 410.

Without the parentheses, `-x \[CenterDot] y` would be parsed as `CenterDot[-x, y]`:

```
FullForm[- x \[CenterDot] y]
```

> CenterDot[Times[-1,x],y]

So, the parentheses are needed so that the output is equivalent to the input.